# Selenium: 'StaleElementReferenceException' when switch to next document for reading excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

Have to handle multiple documents,to verify all the input in the textboxes are correct. For this I'm getting the data from Excel sheet and have to compare the data with data in textbox.
Able to compare it with first document when I switch to next document I'm getting `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.`
Its not reading the data from the second document text box.

```
@Test(priority=4, dataProvider="getTestData")
public void excelUpload(String relatie,String date,String amount,String reknum,String BTW,String btwled,String totaldiff,String btwdiffamt,String bankaccnum) throws Exception {
    
    ocrupload.nextInvoice();
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
    
    String text = ocrupload.relatie();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(text, relatie);
    
    String dat = ocrupload.datum();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(dat, date);
    
    String totamt = ocrupload.txttotal();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(totamt, amount);

    String reknumber = ocrupload.bankaccnumber();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(reknumber, reknum);
    
    String btwNum = ocrupload.btwNumber();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(btwNum, BTW);
    
    String btwledger = ocrupload.btwledger();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(btwledger, btwled);
    
    String btwtotamount = ocrupload.btwtotal();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(btwtotamount, totaldiff);
    
    String totaldifferance = ocrupload.btwDiffamt();
    
    softAssert.assertEquals(totaldifferance, btwdiffamt);

     softAssert.assertAll();








@DataProvider
public Object[][] getTestData(String sheetName) throws InvalidFormatException {
    FileInputStream file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sheet = book.getSheet(sheetName);
    Object[][] data = new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()][sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];
    // System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum() + "--------" +
    // sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum());
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); k++) {
        
            data[i][k] = sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(k).toString();
            
            
        }
    
    
    
    }
    return data;
}
```

````
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'SARAN', ip: '192.168.43.159', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_281'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 90.0.4430.212, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da..., userDataDir: C:\Users\PRASANT\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63398}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 293792ed27516a35838f5e97966cdb47
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.lambda$new$0(EventFiringWebDriver.java:404)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.click(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.click(EventFiringWebDriver.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.sra.qa.TC.Ocrfileupload.nextInvoice(Ocrfileupload.java:228)
    at com.sra.qa.Testcases.mutipleDatadriver.excelUpload(mutipleDatadriver.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)```
````

Comment: Saravanan Selvaraj Please share the exception Log as well.

Comment: @AtulKumarSharma I have added